# How do I achieve this html markup using apex:radioSelect buttons?

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectradio

I'm trying to achieve this markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="category" value="all" checked/><label>All</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="category" value="answers"/><label>Answers</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="category" value="ideas"/><label>Ideas</label></li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="category" value="groups"/><label>Groups</label></li>
</ul>
```

How would I do this using apex:SelectRadio buttons?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. Hope this helps.

**VF page code**

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!searchCategory}" >
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Member" itemlabel="Member"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Blog" itemlabel="Blog"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Photo" itemlabel="Photo"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

**Controller code**

```
public String searchCategory;

public String getsearchCategory() {
    return searchCategory;
}

public void setsearchCategory(String searchCategory) {
    this.searchCategory = searchCategory;
}
```

Source :- http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/07/radio-button-in-salesforce.html

> **Updated solution**

To keep the same HTML structure as in the question, We can use `<apex:repeat` in combination of `<ul>` `<li>` tags. I have used `<apex:inputHidden` tag and JavaScript function to track the selected radio value. Here is a updated version of the code. Hope this helps.

**VF page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="RadioTestController">
    <apex:form>
        <ul>
            <apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="option">
                <li>
                    <input name="rdoname" id="num_{!option}" type="radio" value="{!option}" onclick="saveOptionJS(this,'{!$Component.RadioButtonValue}');" />
                    <label for="num_{!option}">{!option}</label>
                </li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </ul>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!searchCategory}" id="RadioButtonValue" />
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveOptionJS(input, txtid){
            document.getElementById(txtid).value= input.value;
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class RadioTestController {

    Public List<String> myList{get;set;}

    public RadioTestController() {
        myList = new List<String>();
        myList.add('Member');
        myList.add('Blog');
        myList.add('Photo');
    }
    public String searchCategory;

    public String getsearchCategory() {
        return searchCategory;
    }

    public void setsearchCategory(String searchCategory) {
        this.searchCategory = searchCategory;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify: I am trying to replicate the markup so it gets populated like an unordered list.

Comment: @slim I have updated the solution hope this helps.